# Power calculation in a Bayesian approach

Tags: bayesian, statistical-power

Can somebody give me a understanding of what power means in a Bayesian approach?
Or how you would implement it in a Bayesian simulation.

Comment: Does this help? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65754/is-power-analysis-necessary-in-bayesian-statistics